# CENTOS 6.6 "Errno -1 repomd.xml does not match metalink for updates " when trying to use yum command to install openssl

Tags: linux, centos6, yum

Platform: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
When I am trying to yum install openssl, I get this error:

> > epel                                                                                                                                      4 kB     00:00
> >     http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
> >     Trying other mirror.

I have tried : `yum clean all`, `yum info kernel`.

But I still see a similar error

> > epel                                                                                                                          | 4.4 kB     00:00
> >     http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
> >     Trying other mirror.

It looks like I cannot use the yum command to install anything. I have also used `yum clean all` then `yum makecache` but I still see the same problem.

Why do I see this error:

> > [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel

And how do I fix it?

**Solution:** 
Uncomment the baseurl(or add baseurl if it does not exist) and comment out the mirrorlist. This is my temporary workaround in the /etc/yum.repo.d/epel.repo:

```
[epel]  
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
enabled=1
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
sslverify=true
```

Comment: You might want to use http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/CentOS/6.6/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml instead.

Comment: @alvits: How do I use this  http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/CentOS/6.6/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml instead of http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml? Do I change the mirror list?

Comment: I run into the same problem in CentOS 7. I can't add an answer as the question is closed as of now, but in my case rebooting the affected host and retrying `yum install ...` helped.

Comment: A solution that worked for me was clearing metadata and cache: 
`yum clean metadata` and `yum clean all`

https://serverfault.com/a/1021274

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was just running into the same thing. Found elsewhere on the net that it might mean that the mirrors are currently resynchronizing.

I got around it by editing `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and uncommenting the `baseurl` lines and commenting out the `mirrorlist` lines.

You'll probably want to undo that later.

Comment: This is my epel.repo   
`[epel]  
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch

enabled=1  
failovermethod=priority  
gpgcheck=1  
gpgkey=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6  
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch  
sslverify=true`.   I do not see the baseurl lines.

Comment: Try adding this line to that section: `baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch` and comment out the `mirrorlist` line

Comment: Yes adding the `baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch` line and  commenting out the mirrorlist worked!

Comment: This solution worked..

Comment: Not working for me...i am trying to install git

Comment: Solution for me: Wait and come back to it and it fixed itself :-)